# VBA to copy columns into an existing table

Tags: vba, excel

VBA noob here.  I've got Dashboard, Master, and Aggregate sheets.  I created a macro so that when one presses the "create copies" button, the Master sheet is copied into new "Tool" sheets named based on a list.  After the new sheets are created, I'd like specific columns from each of these new sheets to be copied into the aggregate (or inserted as new table columns).  It's difficult when the amount of sheets being added and their names are variable.

Here's the code for creating the new sheets:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set MyRange = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A24:A28")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Worksheets("RTM - Master").Cells.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name = MyCell.Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6).Value = MyCell.Value & " " & "Capability"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = MyCell.Value & " " & "LOE"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 8).Value = MyCell.Value & " " & "Pts"
    Range("f1", Range("f1").End(xlDown)).Select
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!